# How to start an Android Application without loading Activities immediately?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I need something like an "Application Manager" where at first it would setup data storages, network, etc. BEFORE it would show any activities.

As I'm currently designing my android app, in an architectural level.

Comment: Han an Activity that does the setup for you.

Comment: use a splash screen and services or background threads maybe?

Comment: @pmcastillo : Your question doesn't make any sense. What does your app do? Do you understand the concept of UX in the sense that a user should always be given some form of feedback to indicate something is happening? Why don't you want to start an `Activity` when the user launches your app?

Comment: @AndroSelva http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632

Comment: @AlexLockwood : Upvote for that link - I was looking for it and thought I had it bookmarked but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a UI that says *loading..*,  and may be you want to use an `AsyncTask` or some background threads to load the things and then update the UI and say you're ready.